# MTOUCH: Error MT0009: Error while loading assemblies: grpc_csharp_ext.x64.dll (MT0009)

Tags: dll, compiler-errors, assemblies, compiler-warnings, visual-studio-mac

I get a build error using Visual Studio for Mac with an iOS project. It also occurs in an Android project on Mac and in an iOS project in Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10.

I was able to run the project when on an iPhone 8 when it was "clean", before I put any code in it.

Here is the error:

```
/Users/shinehah/VSProjects/iOSAppSpeechToText01/iOSAppSpeechToText01/MTOUCH: Error MT0009: Error while loading assemblies: /Users/shinehah/.nuget/packages/grpc.core/1.18.0/runtimes/win/native/grpc_csharp_ext.x64.dll (MT0009) (iOSAppSpeechToText01)
```

Here are the warnings:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.18.1/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Numerics" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed. (MSB3277) (iOSAppSpeechToText01)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.18.1/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.CSharp" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed. (MSB3277) (iOSAppSpeechToText01)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.18.1/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Net.Http" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed. (MSB3277) (iOSAppSpeechToText01)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.18.1/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190. (MSB3276) (iOSAppSpeechToText01)
/Users/shinehah/VSProjects/iOSAppSpeechToText01/iOSAppSpeechToText01/ViewController.cs(33,33): Warning CS1701: Assuming assembly reference 'Google.Protobuf, Version=3.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a7d26565bac4d604' used by 'Google.LongRunning' matches identity 'Google.Protobuf, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a7d26565bac4d604' of 'Google.Protobuf', you may need to supply runtime policy (CS1701) (iOSAppSpeechToText01)
/Users/shinehah/VSProjects/iOSAppSpeechToText01/iOSAppSpeechToText01/ViewController.cs(29,29): Warning CS1701: Assuming assembly reference 'Google.Protobuf, Version=3.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a7d26565bac4d604' used by 'Google.LongRunning' matches identity 'Google.Protobuf, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a7d26565bac4d604' of 'Google.Protobuf', you may need to supply runtime policy (CS1701) (iOSAppSpeechToText01)
```

The error occurs last, after the warnings.

I didn't add any code whatsoever. The only difference is that I installed Google.Cloud.Speech.V1.

That's everything I changed after a new clean project.

I have tried using Google.Cloud.Speech.V1 1.0.1 package instead of 1.1.0, but I get the same error.

Comment: If you are developing on an Iphone 8, is there a reason you want to use Google Cloud speech to text in C#/.net vs. using Apple's own speech API? I suspect you are going to have a lot of Mono troubleshooting going this way (your question looks like a Mono configuration issue at first glance).

Comment: @paisanco I didn't know Apple has a speech-to-text API. What is it called?

Comment: @paisanco I found it. It's called Speech. Duh!